# ESLint doesn't recognize node.js's 'global' object

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, eslint

The error:

```
3:5  error  'global' is not defined  no-undef
```

My current ESLint config:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    "jest/globals": true,
    jest: true
  },
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      experimentalObjectRestSpread: true,
      jsx: true
    },
    sourceType: "module"
  },
  globals: {
    testGlobal: true
  },
  plugins: ["react", "prettier", "jest"],
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": 1,
    "no-console": 0
  }
};
```

An simplified example test file that causes the ESLint error:

```
describe("Jest global:", () => {
  it("should not cause ESLint error", () => {
    global.testGlobal = {
      hasProp: true
    };
  });
});
```

I expected this Jest feature to be covered by having the `env: { jest: true }` in the eslint config. I can of course disable the rule or line in the file, but then I'd need to do that every time I use `global`.

Comment: Tracked down ESLint's globals dependency https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals/blob/7c53146f46ba4633fda9479d5ecfa6a4d62193c6/globals.json#L925 Seems it doesn't have global in it... I'm guessing it should.

Comment: Filed an issue with the globals project: https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals/issues/118

Figured I'd file an issue with the ESLint team after

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`global` object](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) is part of Node.js. It is not specific to Jest and therefore it's not included in the `jest` environment. In fact, you are running your unit tests in Node and you happen to use the `global` object for your tests. In general the globals defined for specific libraries are the ones they provide to make it more convenient to use them without having to import them. A counterexample would be [AVA, which requires you to import it](https://github.com/avajs/ava#test-syntax) instead of defining globals.

If you want to use ESLint for the tests as well, you would have to add the `node` environment.

```
env: {
  browser: true,
  es6: true,
  node: true,
  jest: true
},
```